# Simplified VBA Code for External Data Source

Tags: sql, vba, excel

so in all my VBA macros that use SQL to query our database, I have just been using what is automatically entered when recording a macro in Excel. Is there a way to simplify it? It inserts it into a table first, but really I just want to the raw data in a spreadsheet... it doesn't need to look nice.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:="ODBC;DSN=AS400;" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandText = strSQL
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_LOCAL_ITEM"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_LOCAL_ITEM").Unlist
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearFormats
```

Comment: After recording any macro, get rid of anything using `Select`, `Selection`, `Activesheet` etc unless you actively want to use that as the input.  EG `Cells.Select: Selection.ClearFormats -> Cells.ClearFormats` and `Sheets("Sheet1").Select: With ActiveSheet -> With Sheets("Sheet1")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot remember the exact code, but can look it up when I get to work again. But depending on which method you use to fetch the data in your SQL (e.g. ADO or DAO), I would do it something like this, if I just wanted the raw data.

If you define a variable as your recordset (for example Dim rst as recordset), VBA has a function to return all data from your recordset, something like:

```
Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst
```

Which will output all the data from the recordset.